# Proof of Hasse's principle for quadratic equations

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am currently tackling the following problem.

**Problem**

Consider the equation $x^2 = q, $ where $ q \in \mathbb{Q}$. Show this has a rational   solution $x$ in $\mathbb{Q}$

if and only if there are real solutions and p-adic solutions in  $\mathbb{Q_p}$ for all prime $p$.

**Progress**

Applying the p-adic norm to both sides of the equation, I deduce $\|x\|_p^2 = \|q\|_p $,

which implies $2v_p(x) = v_p(q)$, where $v_p(x)$ is the p-adic valuation of $x$.

From here I am unsure how to proceed, I would really appreciate some pointers!

Comment: It is low level that there is a solution if and only if $q=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime integers. Connect this with the $p$-adic stuff.

Comment: It may be that you are confused about your goal. For starters, which direction of the equivalence (*if and only if*) are you working on here? One direction is rather straightforward. For the other you should consider the prime factorizations (including the sign) of the numerator and denominator of $q$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen am I correct in saying that the easier direction is proving when the real solutions and p-adic solutions exist, then the rational solution must exist?

Comment: I would have thought that it is easier to show that if a rational solution exists, then so do the real and $p$-adic ones. After all, the rational numbers are a subset of both the reals and the $p$-adics, no?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: You are right just use the embeddings of $\mathbb{Q}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ and the $\mathbb{Q}_p$s to see one direction. The other is more difficult to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended hints:

1. If the equation $x^2=q$ has a rational solution $x=m/n$, then we can view $m/n$ as a real number as well as as a $p$-adic number for all $p$. Therefore the equation has a solution in those fields as well.
2. For the other direction we assume that a rational number $q=m/n$ has a square root in the reals as well as in all the $p$-adics. Using the prime factorizations of both $m$ and $n$ we can write
   $$q=(-1)^\epsilon\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{a_i}$$
   for some finite set of prime numbers $p_i$ and some exponents $a_i\in\Bbb{Z}, i=1,2,\ldots,k$, and some $\epsilon\in\{0,1\}$.

- From the assumption that $q$ has a square root in the reals show that $\epsilon$ must be even.
- From the assumption that $q$ has a square root in $\Bbb{Q}_{p_i}$ show that $a_i$ must be even.
- Deduce that $q$ has a square root in the rationals.

Comment: It's interesting that the local-global principle holds for polynomial equations on $\text{Spec }\mathbb{Z}$, but it doesn't hold for $\text{Spec }\mathbb{C[x,x^{-1}]}$. For example, the equation $X^2 = z$ has local solutions on $\text{Spec }\mathbb{C[x,x^{-1}]}$, but no global solution...